# Nested IF statements in Hive

Tags: sql, if-statement, hive, case

I'm looking to replicate an if statement into my Hive code. Essentially, I have spend from 2014-2018 for a corresponding client, I'm trying to understand the last year the client stopped spending with us and what the loss in $ is based on the previous year's spend. I can't do a CASE statement since there's a couple of variables that I'm looking at for every IF statements but I'm open to suggestions!

```
If (FY_2014 > 0, (If(FY_2015 = 0, FY_2014,0)), 0) as '2014to2015'
    If (FY_2015 > 0, (If(FY_2016 = 0, FY_2015,0)), 0) as '2015to2016'
        If (FY_2016 > 0, (If(FY_2017 = 0, FY_2016,0)), 0) as '2016to2017'
            If (FY_2017 > 0, (If(FY_2018 = 0, FY_2017,0)), 0) as'2017to2018'
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: Try `case` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a nested case?

```
   case when FY_2014 > 0 then case when FY_2015 = 0 then FY_2014 else 0 end else 0 end as "2014to2015",
   case when FY_2015 > 0 then case when FY_2016 = 0 then FY_2015 else 0 end else 0 end as "2015to2016",
   case when FY_2016 > 0 then case when FY_2017 = 0 then FY_2016 else 0 end else 0 end as "2016to2017",
   case when FY_2017 > 0 then case when FY_2018 = 0 then FY_2017 else 0 end else 0 end as "2017to2018"
```

Comment: llya thanks for this!!! So I have a temp table with all clients spend and added in the code you recently built. However, when I try to run the complete code I get an error "  FAILED: ParseException line 1:129 cannot recognize input near 'as' ''2014to2015'' ',' in selection target
hive> "

Comment: Complete code below -                                                                                 
create temporary table spendtest1 as 
select *,
   case when FY_2014 > 0 then case when FY_2015 = 0 then FY_2014 else 0 end else 0 end as '2014to2015',
   case when FY_2015 > 0 then case when FY_2016 = 0 then FY_2015 else 0 end else 0 end as '2015to2016',
   case when FY_2016 > 0 then case when FY_2017 = 0 then FY_2016 else 0 end else 0 end as '2016to2017',
   case when FY_2017 > 0 then case when FY_2018 = 0 then FY_2017 else 0 end else 0 end as '2017to2018'
from spenddata;

Comment: @user10349635 Welcome to StackOverflow! I am glad it worked out for you. In here a thank you is not required, instead, you can mark the question with a V to indicate that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work exactly the same with less conditions.

```
case when FY_2014 > 0 AND FY_2015 = 0 then FY_2014 else 0 end as "2014to2015",
case when FY_2015 > 0 AND FY_2016 = 0 then FY_2015 else 0 end as "2015to2016",
case when FY_2016 > 0 AND FY_2017 = 0 then FY_2016 else 0 end as "2016to2017",
case when FY_2017 > 0 AND FY_2018 = 0 then FY_2017 else 0 end as "2017to2018"
```